# Annotation to build automatic documentation

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, frameworks

I look for any framework that can generate automatically documentation on application.propertie file.

For example, in my Spring Boot 2 bean has this line :

```
@Value("${dbPort:27017}")
private String MONGO_DB_CONN_PORT;
```

And in my application.propertie file I usually use this line :

> dbPort:27017

I would like to use annotation to generate an application.propertie file with a default value and  comments.

For example: I would like to use in my bean

```
@Value("${dbPort:27017}")
@GenerateComment("MongoDb connection port")
private String MONGO_DB_CONN_PORT;
```

and It generates the following lines in the application.propertie:

> #MongoDb connection port
>
> dbPort:27017

Comment: I don't have a tool that does exactly what you ask for, but here is a tool that is similar that you might be able to adapt or take inspiration from.
The [Options](https://github.com/plume-lib/options) package reads `@Option` annotations and generates documentation files based on the annotations, the Javadoc, and the variable initializers. (Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of the Options tool.)  See the [OptionsDoclet](https://github.com/plume-lib/options/blob/master/src/main/java/org/plumelib/options/OptionsDoclet.java) class.